# Text roll button hover effect

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I am working on a button hover effect where the individual characters flip up when you hover. This works almost perfectly but somehow it removes the space in between the words so the button now says 'Thisisatext' instead of 'This is a text', I tried so many things but can't seem to find the right solution:

Demo:

https://codepen.io/pixelarchitect/pen/mdQXjgx

SCSS:

```
.btn-text {
transform: translateY(var(--y)) translateZ(0);
transition: transform 0.3s ease;

  div {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-shadow: 0 1rem 0 white;

    span {
    display: block;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease;
    transform: translateY(var(--m)) translateZ(0);

      @for $i from 1 through 12 {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
          transition-delay: $i * 0.05s;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &:hover {
    span {
      --m: calc(1rem * -1);
    }
  }

}
```

JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-text').forEach(button => {
const words = button.textContent.trim().split(' ');
button.innerHTML = '<div>' + words.map(word => '<span>' + word.split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>').join(' ') + '</div>';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `white-space: pre` to your `<span />`'s

```css
...
span {
      white-space: pre;
      ...
```

preserve whitespace in the JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btn-text").forEach((button) => {
  const words = button.textContent.trim().split("");
  button.innerHTML =
    "<div>" + words.map((word) => `<span>${word}</span>`).join("") + "</div>";
});
```

[working demo (codepen)](https://codepen.io/UndoTemp/pen/NWEYomp)

Answer (score 3):

You are breaking the sentence in single words to then put them back together wrapped in spans; that's when you lose the spaces since span is an inline container.

This is what you get:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-text"><div><span>This</span><span>is</span><span>a</span><span>text</span></div></button>
```

Add a space in HTML code when you put the words together. `&nbsp;`

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-text').forEach(button => {
  const words = button.textContent.trim().split(' ');
  button.innerHTML = '<div>' + words.map(word => '<span>' + word.split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>').join('&nbsp;') + '</div>';
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you reaction, the problem is that it now animates per word and not per character anymore

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren There was an extra space, it should be fixed now.